# Vue transition slide down for each item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-transitions

I'm learning how transitions work with vue. I have a price estimation, when each tab is clicked it will bring up an estimated price per item. I want when the item appears, there is a slide down effect. I tried to find out how, and I got the way by [Enter / Leave & List Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html). And I tried to make it, but the effect still doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this problem?

My Full Code in Codesandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-almeida-rjyy9

**PriceEstimation.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Price Estimation</div>
    <div class="card-body px-0 pt-0">
      <transition name="slide">
        <div class="estimation-category" v-if="cart.total || isDropped">
          <div v-if="cart.storage && cart.storage.totalCost">
            <div class="bg-secondary d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
              <h5 class="text-white m-0">Storage</h5>
              <div>
                <span class="fas fa-pen text-success mr-2" @click="setTab('storage-calculator')"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger" @click="deleteStorage()"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Server Name</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.serverName }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Specification</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.specification.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.specification.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Components</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">vCPU</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.cpu.qty }} GHz</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.cpu.value * cart.storage.cpu.qty }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">vRAM</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.ram.qty }} Gb</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.ram.value * cart.storage.ram.qty }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Capacity</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.capacity.qty }}</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.capacity.value * cart.storage.capacity.qty }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Server Qty</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.server.qty }}</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.server.value * cart.storage.server.qty }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Storage Type</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.storageType.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.storageType.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">OS</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.os.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.os.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Database</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.database.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.database.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Firewall</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.storage.firewall.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.firewall.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Estimate Cost</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.storage.totalCost }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-if="cart.service && cart.service.totalCost">
            <div class="bg-secondary d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
              <h5 class="text-white m-0">Service</h5>
              <div>
                <span class="fas fa-pen text-success mr-2" @click="setTab('service-calculator')"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger" @click="deleteService"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Sub-service</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.service.service.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.service.service.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Package-type</span>
                <span class="ml-2">{{ cart.service.package.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span >${{ cart.service.package.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-2">
              <div>
                <span class="font-weight-bold">Estimate Cost</span>
              </div>
              <span>${{ cart.service.totalCost }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-if="cart.deploy && cart.deploy.totalCost">
            <div class="estimation-category__title">
              <h5 class="m-0 font-size-18 txt-secondary">Cloud Safe</h5>
              <div>
                  <a href="" @click.prevent="setTab('deploy-cloud')"><span class="fas fa-pen text-success font-size-15 mr-2"></span></a>
                  <a href="" @click.prevent="deleteDeploy()"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt text-danger font-size-15"></span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="estimation-category__item">
              <div class="font-size-14 txt-primary">
                <span class="txt-bold">CPU: </span>
                <span class="">{{ cart.deploy.cpuDeploy.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span class="font-size-14 txt-secondary">${{ cart.deploy.cpuDeploy.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="estimation-category__item">
              <div class="font-size-14 txt-primary">
                <span class="txt-bold">RAM: </span>
                <span class="">{{ cart.deploy.ramDeploy.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span class="font-size-14 txt-secondary">${{ cart.deploy.ramDeploy.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="estimation-category__item">
              <div class="font-size-14 txt-primary">
                <span class="txt-bold">Persistant Volume: </span>
                <span class="">{{ cart.deploy.persistant.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span class="font-size-14 txt-secondary">${{ cart.deploy.persistant.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="estimation-category__item">
              <div class="font-size-14 txt-primary">
                <span class="txt-bold">Storage Type: </span>
                <span class="">{{ cart.deploy.workerQty.name }}</span>
              </div>
              <span class="font-size-14 txt-secondary">${{ cart.deploy.workerQty.value }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="estimation-category__item">
                <div class="border-cost">
                  <div class="txt-primary">
                      <span class="txt-bold font-size-16">Estimate Cost</span>
                  </div>
                  <span class="font-size-16 txt-secondary">${{ cart.deploy.totalCost }}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <table class="table table-borderless">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p>TOTAL</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  <p>${{ cart.total }}</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    setTab: {type: Function},
  },
  data: () => ({
    isDropped: false
  }),
  computed: {
    cart () {
      this.isDropped = !this.isDropped;
      return this.$store.getters.getCart;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteStorage() {
      this.$store.commit('deleteStorage');
    },
    deleteService() {
      this.$store.commit('deleteService');
    },
    deleteDeploy() {
      this.$store.commit('deleteDeploy');
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to{
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
.estimation-category{
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: maybe you're wrong in the if condition and your computed

Comment: How it should be? @Frauds

Answer (score 4):

In Vue 3 the transition class names have been changed slightly, for consistency. Read [docs here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-enterleave.html#transition-classes).

In short, both transition types (`leave` and `enter`) now start from `{name}-{type}-from`, end at `{name}-{type}-to` and have `{name}-{type}-active` applied while the transition is active.

[image]

Which means you have to replace `.slide-enter` with `.slide-enter-from` (`slide-enter` is no longer applied in Vue 3). e.g:

```
.slide-enter-from,
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
.estimation-category {
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

See it [working here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-fire-gl2gm?file=/src/components/price-calculator/PriceEstimation.vue).

Which fixes one transition.
If you want to have an individual transition for each cart item, you'll likely want to use `<transition-group>` instead of `<transition>` and run a `v-for` on the `cartItems` array, but the animation would be pretty much the same.
Here's a minimal example:

```js
const Cart = {
  data: () => ({
    items: []
  }),
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      const lastItemId = this.items.length
        ? this.items[this.items.length - 1].id 
        : -1;
      this.items.push({id: lastItemId + 1, name: `item-${lastItemId + 1}`})
    },
    removeItem(item) {
      this.items = this.items.filter(el => el.id !== item.id)
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(Cart).mount('#cart')
```

```css
.cart-item-wrapper {
  max-height: 53px;
  transition: max-height .35s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1), margin-bottom .35s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 2px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide-enter-from,
.slide-leave-to {
  max-height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.cart-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.cart-item button {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
#cart {
  max-width: 360px;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <transition-group name="slide">
    <div class="cart-item-wrapper"
         :key="item.id"
         v-for="(item, key) in items">
      <div class="cart-item">
        {{ item.name }}
        <button @click="removeItem(item)">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition-group>
  <button @click="addItem">Add Item</button>
</div>
```

In the above `<transition-group>` example I used a different transition than yours, but that shouldn't matter. The class names are the important bit and the fact the items are keyed by `id`, so the leaving transitions are mapped correctly (if, for example, we used their index in array as key, the leave transition would always happen on the last element).

Comment: I like the second transition, using ```transition-group```. But does it have to use v-for? If I still use static data like in my codesandbox, can I use it?

Comment: You can use any transition you want. If you want to use v-for, you have to use `<transition-group>`. When you deal with only one item, you use `<transition>`. In both, the important bit is to change `.slide-enter` into `.slide-enter-from` in your CSS. The rest are details.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not working because you are using the wrong css class. Give a name to the transition you want to use like :

```
    <transition name="fade">
      <p v-if="show">hello</p>
    </transition>
```

fade is the name of the transition here, therefore you can use it in your css like this:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want the fade in and fade out effect. I've explained in the post above, that I want a ```slide down``` effect. And I want to ask if the placement of my transition tag is correct or is it still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Vue transition wrappers affects only its immediate child. So you should organize your code based on this.
I created a new `show` property and a button to set it to quickly show how it works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-dirac-npi9s?file=/src/components/price-calculator/PriceEstimation.vue

In this case `.estimation-category` is animated, but in the original example, you are displaying its child based on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Vue 2. You can find the dynamic CSS classes in the docs. I would recommend having the transition controller outside of transition element. Also, please ensure that the content inside `transition` block becomes completely empty, in your case there is still some default content that is left.
I used this CSS in my project which worked for me adjusted according to your transition name `slide`.

```
.slide-enter-active {
  @include transition-ease(all, .7s);
}

.slide-leave-active {
  @include transition-ease(all, .5s);
}

.slide-enter-to,
.slide-leave {
  max-height: 490px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-enter,
.slide-leave-to {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<transition-group name="slide">
      <li>        
            item.name
      </li>
            item2.name
      <li>
</transition-group>
```

You can also use v-for here for li element(s).

This is styling:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.slide-item {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}
.slide-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.slide-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```